# Separate fill-column value for org-mode

Tags: org-mode, auto-fill-mode

I've set `fill-column` value to be 80. But, especially for org-mode I want a bit higher fill-column value. Is it possible for `org-mode` to have a separate `fill-column` value of say 100?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
   (lambda () (setq fill-column 100)))
```